# for loop save to array but skip saving elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I want a fancy oneliner that doesn't read all of the files I'm looking at into memory, but still processes them all, and saves a nice sample of them.

The oneliner I would like to do is:

```
def foo(findex):
    return [bar(line) for line in findex] # but skip every nth term
```

But I would like to be able to not save every nth line in that. i.e., I still want it to run (for byte position purposes), but I don't want to save the image, because I don't have enough memory for that.

So, if the output of bar(line) is `1,2,3,4,5,6,...` I would like it to still run on `1,2,3,4,5,6,...` but I would like the return value to be `[1,3,5,7,9,...]` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `enumerate` to get the index, and a filter using modulo to take every other line:

```
return [bar(line) for i,line in enumerate(findex) if i%2]
```

Generalize that with `i%n` so everytime that the index is divisible by `n` then `i%n==0` and `bar(line)` isn't issued into the listcomp.

`enumerate` works for *every* iterable (file handle, generator ...), so it's way better than using `range(len(findex))`

Now the above is incorrect if you want to call `bar` on *all* the values (because you need the side effect generated by `bar`), because the filter prevents execution. So you have to do that in 2 passes, for instance using `map` to apply your function to all items of `findex` and pick only the results you're interested in (but it guarantees that *all* of the lines are processed) using the same modulo filter but *after* the execution:

```
l = [x for i,x in enumerate(map(bar,findex)) if i%n]
```

Comment: would it  be `if not(i%n)` for the 1/n case? is 0 true in python?

Comment: yes, but OP wants to skip one line from time to time. Of course when `n==2` that's ambiguous :)

Comment: Oh, yes, the question does say that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, as I'm trying this, this seems to fail to actually run the inbetween values.
So, i have a `print(count)` in `bar()`, and it's skipping lines.
So, it's only running `bar(line) # output 1`, and `bar(line) #output 5`

Comment: bar takes in a line, and not findex, is this still possible?

would it need to be `map(bar, line for line in findex)`? Does that work?

Comment: `line for line in findex` is doing the same thing as `findex`, albeit slower :) try it.

Answer (score 0):

If `findex` is subscriptable (accepts `[]` operator with indices), you can try this way :

```
def foo(findex):
    return [bar(findex[i]) for i in range (0, len(findex), 2) ]
```

Comment: except that `findex` must be subscriptable for that to work. Pass it a file handle and it doesn't work.